# Target class controller [controllerName] not found in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

When I hit my register route using Postman, it gave me the following error:

```
My api.php route:
Route::get('register', 'Api\RegisterController@register');
```

Here is my controller:

Comment: How more descriptive do you want the error message to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the official Laravel 8 upgrade guide, you can see that controllers are no longer namespaced by default. This hinders the automatic class resolution with `'Controller@method'` syntax.

See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#automatic-controller-namespace-prefixing

The new way of registering routes is to use the following syntax:

```php
// routes/api.php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\RegisterController;

Route::get('register', [RegisterController::class, 'register');
```

You can also adapt your `RouteServiceProvider.php` file to "re-enable" the old way to auto-load your controllers using the correct namespace with `@` syntax:

```php
// App/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php

public function boot()
{
    // ...

    Route::prefix('api')
        ->middleware('api')
        ->namespace('App\Http\Controllers') // put your namespace here
        ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for global solutions and we don't require to each controller.

Answer (score 0):

It should be changed to:

```php
Route::get('register', [RegisterController::class, 'register']);
```

Comment: If the namespace is correct, you can still use the 'old' way like in the question.

Comment: Laravel 8 updated RouteServiceProvider and it affects routes with the string syntax.

Comment: I know, and your way is the correct way, but still, you can use the string syntax.  I would explain it a little more: for example: a use statement is needed for your code to work, the namespace needs to be correct (since that is the problem with the current route)

Comment: Agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

first, in the route add the controller name.

```
use App\Http\Controllers\RegisterController;
```

In the route use like this way

```
Route::get('register', [RegisterController::class, 'register']);
```

Comment: Also, that will work for me. But Upper solutions is global and we don't require to each controller.

Thanks for your support